# Is it good idea to change complete enterprise level application into ajax web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json

I am working on an application which is completely written using server side method in asp.net web forms with c# .

Now my team lead wants to convert whole application to ajax , in that approach we need to do the following tasks one by one .

1- Change all page methods into web methods so all will be static methods

2- Use jquery ajax to call all web methods .

3- bind html using json response.

Now i am  looking for some framework which can make my json html binding work bit easy but most of the frameworks like (knockout) are much compatible with MVC framework .

I have two main concern points:

1. Is it good idea to convert all  methods into web methods and use ajax ?
2. If i have to work with this approach what is the best framework i can use ?

Comment: I've worked on integrating a custom ajax engine into existing mvc project. We had to do the change to improve performance. It took us quite a time and effort and many new bugs appeared. So if there is a way to avoid the huge change, avoid it. If no, be very consistent in how you are making the migration and make backups after big changes so that you can go back if anything goes wrong.

Comment: AJAX communication and responsive web design are not the same thing, and it sounds like your developer lead has made assumptions about the benefits. You'll need to move a ton of code to JS before you see performance gains.

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean by "good idea"?

Good idea for whom?

Does your company have pots of money to spend on the whim of an architect?

Using ajax techniques can provide a much better user experience, there is no doubt about that.

Are your end clients, whoever they are, complaining about the way the app works? Is this just going to be part of a rewrite that is planned anyway?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it good idea to convert all methods into web methods and use ajax ? If i have to work with this approach what is the best framework i can use ?

There is no silver bullet, however it would make sense to convert once that have validation check on business logic. Thus, you may warn/feedback user before post-backing the form by reducing the costly round-trips to the server.

There is a [**MVP design pattern**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx) for ASP.NET web forms. It may help to reduce concerns of tight binding that you get out of the box with ASP.NET forms.

ps: If you start a new project, then ASP.net MVC is a better choice. But if you just want to refactor an existing project as you just said, then MVP is the option because there is no easy way to convert those web-forms codes to MVC pattern.

**References** that might be helpful:

- [MVP Pattern Implementation in ASP.NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/subhendude/model-view-presenter-pattern-implementation-in-Asp-Net/)
- [Convert ASP.net website to AJAX enabled website?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1144152.aspx/1)
- [Converting from ASP.net to Ajax enabled web site](http://buddhikas.wordpress.com/2007/10/29/converting-from-aspnet-to-ajax-enabled-web-site/)
- [Migrating ASP.NET Web Forms to the MVC Pattern with the ASP.NET Web API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991978.aspx)

Comment: If you don't plan to unit-test the view then MVP is overkill. The code behind can act as "controller" and delegate tasks to services / repositories / whatever.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to your question - "is this a good idea" and "should we do it like this"

To answer the first you need to answer the question of what problem are you trying to solve i.e. what issues with the current system do you (does your project lead or whoever requires the change) believe that this change will resolve? Unless you have a clear understanding of this then its a "because we can" project and that's not a good idea.

To answer the second, erm, no... that doesn't look like a sensible approach. You first need to isolate business logic and data access from the user interface (c.f. the MVP references provided by others) that done you can look at the architecture you want for your client side application and build the API you need to support that (which should sit upon substantially the same business and data access logic you've separated from your existing user interface).

Comment: We are using Nhibernate as well..